# Get users for a given group Activiti Rest API

Tags: json, alfresco, activiti

I'm looking for some advice on how to approach retrieving the users from a given group of the activti-app. Having read the documentation I've attempted to hit the endpoint associated with users and their groups by a posting a JSON body containing an array of user task filter ids.

Testing this in Postman returns a 500 internal server error "exception": "Request method 'POST' not supported". Obviously this is because I should be making a GET request however I cannot attach a JSON body in that case.

Aforementioned example endpoint:  localhost:8080/activiti-app/api/enterprise/groups/{group_id}/users

Aforementioned docs:
https://docs.alfresco.com/activiti/docs/dev-guide/1.5.0/#_user_and_group_lists

Specifically this section [Screencap of activti docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wa5H.png)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: From a quick look at the docs, you should be putting your filter options as a url parameter of `filter` not posting a JSON body - JSON is only used for the results

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks for the advice! I have tried appending a query parameter directly to the URL e.g. http://localhost:8080/activiti-app/api/enterprise/admin/users?email="test@gmail.com" and have had no luck yet. I will conduct some more investigation into the API documentation so see what the capabilities are regarding url parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we have to make sure we are talking about "organization groups" not "capabilities groups". That was my original confusion. Once I create the right kind of group I could successfully use the REST API to fetch both a list of groups and a list of group members.

As the docs point out, to get a list of groups, do this:

```
curl -uadmin@app.activiti.com http://localhost:8080/activiti-app/api/enterprise/groups
```

Which returns:

```
{
    "size":2,
    "total":2,
    "start":0,
    "data":[
       {"id":5,"name":"test-org-group-1","externalId":null,"status":"active","groups":null},
       {"id":6,"name":"test-org-group-2","externalId":null,"status":"active","groups":null}
    ]
}
```

If you want to pass a filter, do it with "?filter=some-group-name".

Now, to see the members of a specific group, pass in the group ID, which is a numeric. So to see the members of test-org-group-1 I would use:

```
curl -uadmin@app.activiti.com http://localhost:8080/activiti-app/api/enterprise/groups/5/users
```

Which returns:

```
{
    "size":2,
    "total":2,
    "start":0,
    "data": [
        {"id":2,"firstName":"Test","lastName":"User1","email":"tuser1@metaversant.com"},
        {"id":3,"firstName":"Test","lastName":"User2","email":"tuser2@metaversant.com"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Fantastic explanation, thank you very much for your time!