# activiti - Assigning a task to a group or a user

Tags: groovy, activiti, bpmn, alfresco-enterprise

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to assign a simple task to a person **OR** a group based on the value they select in a group/people picker.

So in my UI a user can select **either** a *person* or *group* using the relevant person/group picker controls.

[image: picker controls]

Using the activiti assignment properties, I set the *Assignee* as `${selectedPerson}` and *Candidate Groups* as `${selectedGroup}`. These variables relate to the values of the picker controls mentioned above:

[image: assignment]

The overall goal is that the user **should** be able to assign the task to either a person or a group, however the design above presents the following problems:

- When a user selects a group, the task is assigned successfully to a group, presumably the Assignee value is nullable.
- However, when a user selects a person but not a group, Activiti throws the following exception as it expects a group;

> org.activiti.engine.ActivitiIllegalArgumentException: Expression did
>   not resolve to a string or collection of strings

What is the correct way to do this?

---

### Full Stacktrace

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.activiti.engine.ActivitiIllegalArgumentException: Expression did not resolve to a string or collection of strings
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:97)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:149)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    com.activiti.security.CustomStatelessCSRFFilter.doFilterInternal(CustomStatelessCSRFFilter.java:68)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

Comment: can you upload the complete stacktrace please?

Comment: @AbbasKararawala Sure, check my latest edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Activiti accepts Candidate Group's ID as a string or comma-separated values of string. but the form element (as you have selected) stores the group ID of the selected group as a Long, hence the `IllegalArgumentException`. try storing the variable as string after it is selected by the user, then pass this string as the Candidate group.

The method that you are using will only satisfy if both `${selectedPerson}` and `${selectedGroup}` has non null values.

Alternatively, you can create a Task Listener on the task to be assigned and execute the logic.

Something like:

```
public class CustomTaskListener implements TaskListener {
    @Override
    public void notify(DelegateTask delegateTask) {
    // get required variables
        String selectedPerson = (String) delegateTask.getVariable("selectedPerson");
        String selectedGroup = (String) delegateTask.getVariable("selectedGroup");
    // check for the condition
        if (null != selectedPerson && !selectedPerson.isEmpty()) {
    // set values
            delegateTask.setAssignee(selectedPerson);
        } else {
            delegateTask.addCandidateGroup(selectedGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abbas, ill try that now

Comment: I think this might work, however I still get an error if i dont supply a string for ${selectedPerson} - `Unknown property used in expression: ${selectedPerson}`. I was under the impression that the Assignee field was nullable?

Comment: do you want just the assignee or just the candidate group? or both of them at the same time?

Comment: I need either or. The problem with the UI is that it cant check if either one is null i.e. we cannot write an expression for dynamic assignment. The main use case is that i need to assign to group if group picker is populated, assign to specific user if people picker is populated. Right now its forcing me to set up an outcome for both but failing when one of them is null

Comment: Thanks Abbas, im not familiar with task listeners and have no access to spring bean definitions etc, can this be set up from within the process instance in the designer?

Comment: yes, you can try ScriptTaskListener using the same logic as above. this should help you getting started: https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#taskListeners

Comment: Thanks Abbas, appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't give two assignees as **Assignee and Candidate Groups** both , if you wanted assign task to a user or to a group

Then use **Candidate Users** as assignee which accepts array of users set a variable as array if your first condition need to **true then add that user** to **array** else **iterate the group members and add all the group members** to the **array** and pass this array variable to **Candidate Users** as assignee.

Comment: Thanks Vikash. Ill give this a go

Comment: What method can I use to return all members of a specified group?

Comment: Yes you can give Assignee and Candidate Groups for a single task. Assignee is the one who can complete the task, candidate groups can see the task but cannot complete it.

Comment: please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619148/get-users-for-a-given-group-activiti-rest-api

Comment: this will help you more https://community.alfresco.com/thread/227396-dynamically-assign-a-list-of-users-as-candidate-assignees

Comment: @AbbasKararawala we can't give Assignee and Candidate Groups for the same task we can give either  Assignee or Candidate Groups

Comment: @vikash i consider you try it first please. i've already tested this scenario

Comment: Thanks for the help Vikash